# Java - Download PDF from bytes which are coming as string?

Tags: java, inputstream, fileinputstream

We are calling some API which is returning bytes as String and I need to download PDF from that byte stream (which is coming as String).

e.g.

```
download_pdf":[{"name":"Transaction_Details.pdf","value":"JVBERi0xLjQNCiXi48/TDQoyIDAgb2JqCjw8L051bXNbMCAzIDAgUl..."}]
```

When trying to write file from it its getting corrupted and not opening the file.

```
try {
                    return ResponseEntity.ok()
                            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" +item.getName())
                            .body(item.getValue().getBytes());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Tried below code also but no success.

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(item.getValue().getBytes()(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

How to Create InputStream OR byte[] from file/bytes (which is coming as a String)?

Comment: it's hard to believe a pdf-file-content in a JSON-String is not encoded in one or the other way. If not, i'm not surprised about corruption.

Comment: The structure is insane, but you seem to have a Base64-encoded PDF. (This does nothing except dramatically increase the bandwidth required to send the file and to require special handling on both ends, including preventing browser download functionality from working.) You'll need to pull the `value` and Base64 decode it. Note that there are multiple variants of Base64; confirm which one to use.

Comment: Thank you @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Base64 decode solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Structure is the API response which is not owned by us so cannot help on that part. But as suggested by ***cautiouslyoptimistic*** in one of the comment ***Base64 decode*** solved the problem. I am accepting his answer and adding as new comment.

````
 Base64 decoder = new Base64();
                    byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode(item.getValue());
                    return ResponseEntity.ok()
                            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, ATTACHMENT_FILENAME +item.getName())
                            .body(decodedBytes);```
````